# Angular replacing .scss using docker-compose does not affect

Tags: angular, docker, sass, docker-compose, styles

I have a frontend application written in Angular 8. I would like to have different colour themes on each environment (test/acc/prod). So I created different variables.scss files like this:

- variables.test.scss
- variables.acc.scss
- variables.prod.scss
  in my assets/scss folder inside Angular project.

I'm using docker-compose for deployment and I replace the variables.scss file with specific one based on an environment. Below is my part of docker-compose for test environment:

```
(...)
my-angular-application:
    image: my.registry.pl/my-angular-application:${MY_ANGULAR_APPLICATION_IMAGE_TAG}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    volumes:
      - ./env/variables.test.scss:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/scss/variables.scss
    networks:
      - backtier
(...)
```

The `variables.scss` after `docker-compose up` command is successfully replaced (I went into a container and checked it) - but after I open the app on the browser the application has the default style from the default `variables.scss` file, not the one I coppied :/

Why is it not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are changing the variable file after the angular compilation ?
If it's the case, it will never work as those files are already processed

Then you need to run a script before angular compilation to replace your file

You can achieve this by creating a script that do your file replacement and then launch ng build, you can then reference this script in package.json "scripts" value so that you can use it with npm

---

EDITED out because this is actually a bug in angular (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451) :

You can achieve this with angular.json if you have specific build configuration for each environment
You need to set the file replace in angular.json
In that example I replace environment.ts with environment.ci.ts

```
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "deploy/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "deploy/environments/environment.ci.ts"
                }
              ],
```

Comment: I tried this way, but this is common problem that filereplacing functionality is not working for a scss files - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11451

Comment: indeed, I didn't know about that. When are you running the ng build ?

Comment: My CI/CD is doing this (Jenkins)  just before pushing the docker image with the given tag to the our registry. So as you said, the file replacement using docker-compose is done after the build.